# Can Javascript validation and ASP.NET Validators work simultaneously

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, c#-4.0

i have two question here

- i used both javascript validation and ASP.NET Validators ,but .net validators is not working completely,it is showing validation messages but when i click on submit form gets submit
- another is ,in javascript validation email validation is not working,i have written email validation function in aspx file and rest javascript validation in cs file

in email validation when i use getElementById it showing nothing but when i use getElementByName it showing validation message ,even if email is right it shows validation message and form gets submit too

email validation function in aspx file-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkEmail() {
    var email = document.getElementsByName('txtremail');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) 
    {
        alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        email.focus;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

submit button -

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="submitbtn" runat="server"
        ImageUrl="~/images/joinnow.jpg" CssClass="joinbtn" 
    ValidationGroup="join" onclick="submitbtn_Click" OnClientClick="return checkEmail()"/>
```

and in cs file i have used if conditions,because of which i think form gets submit even if email is invalid

cs file code is -

```
 public bool chkpass(string pass, string conpass)
{
    if (pass.Equals(conpass))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
protected void submitbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtruname.Text != "" && txtrfname.Text != "" && txtrpass.Text != "" && txtremail.Text != "" && txtrdesc.Text != "")
    {
        if (!chkpass(txtrpass.Text, txtrcnpass.Text))
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "alert('password does not match');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            dl.req_username = txtruname.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = bl.reqruiter_uname(dl);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               lblwarning.Text = "username exists";
            }
            else
            {
                dl.req_fullname = txtrfname.Text;
                dl.req_username = txtruname.Text;
                dl.req_password = txtrpass.Text;
                dl.req_email = txtremail.Text;
                dl.req_description = txtrdesc.Text;
                bl.reqruiter_registration(dl);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "", "alert('please fill all info');", true);
    }
```

so,what should i do to make form to not submit when email is wrong?
and if possible how can i write email validation in cs file ,so it can satisfy if condition on submit click,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [unobtrusive validation for web forms](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/using-unobstructive-validation-in-asp.net-4.5-web-forms.htm). [One more link](http://brijbhushan.net/2011/11/13/unobtrusive-validation-with-asp-net-4-5/).